# Code written using multiprocessing module is not giving any output

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

So I am trying to learn multiprocessing module and have written a code(below) where **4 processes** are generated and are assigned **8 jobs** (in the **processor function**) and each job contains just a sleep function (in the **example job function**).Now I have written the similar code in **multithreading module** there is was working fine but here it is not outputting any thing.Please help

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
import multiprocessing 
import time

print_lock = Lock()

def exampleJob(worker):                 # function simulating some computation
    time.sleep(.5)
    print_lock.acquire()
    print(multiprocessing.current_process.pid,worker)
    print_lock.release()

def processor():                         #function where process pick up the job
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        exampleJob(worker)
        q.task_done()

q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
process = []

for x in range(4):
     p = multiprocessing.Process(target=processor)
     process.append(p)

for i in range(0,len(process)):
    process[i].start

start = time.time()
for worker in range(8):
    q.put(worker)
q.join()

print('Entire job took:',time.time() - start)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first problem is `start` needs to be `start()`.

Also, separate processes have separate global variables, so `print_lock = Lock()` is a different lock in each process.  You have to create the lock once and pass it to the individual processes.  This goes for the queue as well.

A `JoinableQueue` isn't really needed.  What's needed is a sentinel flag to tell the processes to exit, and join the processes.

Working example with other fixes:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def exampleJob(print_lock,worker):                 # function simulating some computation
    time.sleep(.5)
    with print_lock:
        print(mp.current_process().name,worker)

def processor(print_lock,q):                       # function where process pick up the job
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        if worker is None: # flag to exit the process
            break
        exampleJob(print_lock,worker)

# This "if" required for portability in some OSes.
# Windows for example creates new Python processes and imports the original script.
# Without this the below code would run again in each child process.
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print_lock = mp.Lock()
    q = mp.Queue()
    processes = [mp.Process(target=processor,args=(print_lock,q)) for _ in range(4)]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()   # OP code didn't *call* the start method.

    start = time.time()
    for worker in range(8):
        q.put(worker)

    for process in processes:
        q.put(None) # quit indicator

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    print('Entire job took:',time.time() - start)
```

Output:

```
Process-2 2
Process-1 0
Process-3 1
Process-4 3
Process-3 6
Process-1 5
Process-2 4
Process-4 7
Entire job took: 1.1350018978118896
```

Comment: thank you for your answer I have two questions isn't it required that to perform lock in multiprocessing we should use acquire() and release() and second one while I am running your code in online compiler it is giving the output as stated but when I am running it on my machine it is only giving the  final output  that is the time taken and not the whole output

Comment: @louis Locks support the context manager interface, so when used with `with` acquire is called when entering the `with` and release is called when exiting it.  It's a convience that you don't have to remember to call release.  Are you using an IDE on your machine?  Some IDEs don't handle multiprocessing.  The new processes aren't attached to the same terminal and you don't see the output.  Run in a simple terminal such as cmd.exe on Windows.

Comment: I am using the normal python shell

Comment: @louisphilippe What is the "normal python shell"?  IDLE?  That is an IDE that doesn't support multiprocessing correctly, at least on Windows.  Be specific.  What OS are you on?  Use a command window instead of IDLE if on Windows.

Comment: yes it is IDE nevermind it's working on cmd one last question though  why you didn't use joinablequeue class which is specifically designed for multiprocessing and has functions like task_done() and join()

Comment: @louisphilippe JoinableQueue gives you a way to know all the tasks in the queue are done, but doesn't do anything for ending the processes.  Instead I used a regular queue and posted a "task" for each process as the last jobs in the queue that makes it stop pulling tasks and exit, then join on the processes when they all exit.  If you had long-running processes that didn't needed to exit a JoinableQueue might be appropriate.